# Prove that A == B, B==C, A != C

Tags: java, algorithm, logic

Can there be objects or primitive types where the transitive law can not hold true; for example

A == B, B == C but A != B

I am not talking about equals() method. I am interested in == operative

Can we prove this ?

Comment: The answer is no; reference equality is an equivalence relation, equality on all non-floating point types is an equivalence relation, and equality on float and double is transitive and symmetric but not reflexive.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I am told that this can be proven, and it has kept me very curious

Comment: I'm not certain what a "proof" would entail here.  Would this property being specified by the JLS suffice?

Comment: @LouisWasserman It would be to create a scenario where a certain type of object would hold true for what I have mentioned in the question.

Comment: That would prove that transitivity does not hold, but transitivity does hold if A, B, and C are all simple identifiers.  How would you expect your claim to be proved false?  (If you allow mutation or method calls all bets are off, and I suspect weird casting crap might also break it, but that's cheating.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Is NaN the non-reflexive case you were considering?

Comment: @LouisWasserman could you give me the NaN example please

Comment: NaN is not equal to anything, including itself, but that does not break transitivity.

Comment: I have a counter-example to transitivity.

Comment: ...and a second one using only primitive types.

Comment: ... and (I think) a third one using non fp-strict code (and if this one is valid, it's a counterexample to == being transitive when A, B and C are of the same type).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here you go. `A==B` and `B==C` cause the `Float`s to get promoted to float, so `==` returns true. However, `A==C` is reference equality, which is false.

```
    Float A = new Float(1.0f);
    float B = 1.0f;
    Float C = new Float(1.0f);
    System.out.println(A==B);
    System.out.println(B==C);
    System.out.println(A==C);
```

`Float` isn't special here, it could just as easily be `Integer` or `Boolean`.

Here's the relevant sections from the language specification:

> 15.21.1. Numerical Equality Operators == and !=
>
> If the operands of an equality operator are both of numeric type, or
>   one is of numeric type and the other is convertible (§5.1.8) to
>   numeric type, binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands
>   (§5.6.2).

and

> 15.21.3. Reference Equality Operators == and !=
>
> If the operands of an equality operator are both of either reference
>   type or the null type, then the operation is object equality.

Here's a second counter-example, this time using the fact that comparing a `long` and `float` is done using `float` comparison.

```
        long a = 99999999999999L;
        float b = 99999999999999.0f;
        long c = 99999999999998L;
        System.out.println(a==b);
        System.out.println(b==c);
        System.out.println(a==c);
```

Thirdly, I believe it's also possible in theory for non-transitivity to exist even if A, B and C are the same type.

If A and C are [double-extended-exponent values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3) (that have the same value B as the nearest double to them), then when A==B and B==C are calculated, the language implementation may choose to round A and C to their nearest double value (which is B). It may equally choose *not* to round when A==C is performed. The comparisons would have to be done in a context that's not marked as FP-strict

Essentially "5.1.13. Value Set Conversion" gives Java a limited implementation-defined set of behaviors for non-FP-strict float/double calculations, and this can be leveraged (at least in theory) to find a counter-example to equality transitivity.

Comment: The concept of autoboxin and unboxing in Java I guess holds true

Answer (score 1):

From Swift comes a very bizarre example of this. Rather than a reference semantic being at play, here, the degree to which a nested optional has been wrapped, and the degree to which the compiler explicitly unwraps that optional, comes into play:

```
let a = nil as Int? as Int?? as? Int?
let b = nil as Int? as Int?? 
let c: Int? = nil

assert(b == a) // passes

assert(c == a && c == nil && a != nil) // passes. wtf
assert(c == b && u == nil && b != nil) // passes. wtf
```